# Enabling recording devices programmatically

Tags: c#, c++, .net, windows, naudio

Enabling recording devices programmatically

I want to enable the disabled device in Sound - Recording devices list programmatically

[image]

I was able to get a list of disabled devices using [Naudio](https://github.com/naudio/NAudio)

But there is no way to enable it using Naudio.

so I tried also using [IMMDevice interface](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/mmdeviceapi/nf-mmdeviceapi-immdevice-getstate) but I couldn't find out how to do this.

I tried also Registry Edit

```
//Computer\HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\MMDevices\Audio\Render\{87bd5990-b012-41f1-83f7-f267ed7780a7}
    RegistryKey root = Registry.LocalMachine.OpenSubKey("SOFTWARE", true).OpenSubKey("Microsoft", true).OpenSubKey("Windows", true).OpenSubKey("CurrentVersion", true).OpenSubKey("MMDevices", true).OpenSubKey("Audio", true).OpenSubKey("Render", true).OpenSubKey("{87bd5990-b012-41f1-83f7-f267ed7780a7}", true); //{87bd5990-b012-41f1-83f7-f267ed7780a7} any Playback Device ID
    MessageBox.Show($"Value Before {root.GetValue("DeviceState")}   { root.GetValueKind("DeviceState")}");
    root.SetValue("DeviceState", 0x10000001, RegistryValueKind.DWord);
    MessageBox.Show($"Value After {root.GetValue("DeviceState")}    { root.GetValueKind("DeviceState")}");
```

or

```
Registry.SetValue(@"HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\MMDevices\Audio\Render\{87bd5990-b012-41f1-83f7-f267ed7780a7}", "DeviceState", 0x10000001, RegistryValueKind.DWord);
```

but this will need Administrator Rights and I want it to work for any user.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found this solution and I am not sure if there is any other solution :

Using [NAudio](https://github.com/naudio/NAudio) and [TestStack.White](https://github.com/TestStack/White) you can open the Sounds List and enable and close it this will not need for admin privileges:

```
using NAudio.CoreAudioApi;
using System;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Linq;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace Enable_Device
{
class Program
{
    [DllImport("User32.dll")]
    public static extern Int32 FindWindow(String lpClassName, String lpWindowName);

    [DllImport("user32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
    static extern uint GetWindowThreadProcessId(IntPtr hWnd, out uint processId);

    [DllImport("user32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto)]
    private static extern IntPtr SendMessage(IntPtr hWnd, UInt32 Msg, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam);


    private const UInt32 WM_CLOSE = 0x0010;

    static void CloseWindow(IntPtr hwnd)
    {
        SendMessage(hwnd, WM_CLOSE, IntPtr.Zero, IntPtr.Zero);
    }
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string driverName = "Stereo Mix"; // any device name you want to enable

        MMDevice mMDevice;
        using (var enumerator = new NAudio.CoreAudioApi.MMDeviceEnumerator())
        {
            mMDevice = enumerator.EnumerateAudioEndPoints(DataFlow.Capture, DeviceState.Disabled).ToList().Where(d => d.FriendlyName.ToLower().Contains(driverName.ToLower())).FirstOrDefault();
        }
        if (mMDevice != null)
        {
            driverName = mMDevice.FriendlyName;
            int charLocation = driverName.IndexOf("(", StringComparison.Ordinal);

            if (charLocation > 0)
            {
                driverName = driverName.Substring(0, charLocation);
                driverName = driverName.Trim();
            }
        }
        else
        {

            MessageBox.Show($"{driverName} Coudn't Found as Disabled Device.");

            return;
        }
        TryEnable(driverName, mMDevice);

    
    }

    private static void TryEnable(string driverName, MMDevice mMDevice)
    {
        try
        {
            var hwnd = 0;
            hwnd = FindWindow(null, "Sound");
            Process soundProc;
            if (hwnd == 0)
            {
                soundProc = Process.Start("control.exe", "mmsys.cpl,,1");
            }
            else
            {
                CloseWindow((IntPtr)hwnd);
                while (hwnd == 0)
                {
                    Debug.WriteLine($"Waiting to Close ...");
                
                    hwnd = FindWindow(null, "Sound");
                }
                soundProc = Process.Start("control.exe", "mmsys.cpl,,1");
            }
            hwnd = 0;
            hwnd = FindWindow(null, "Sound");
            while (hwnd == 0)
            {
                Debug.WriteLine($"Waiting ...");
                
                hwnd = FindWindow(null, "Sound");
            }
            if (hwnd == 0)
            {

                MessageBox.Show($"Couldnt find Sound Window.");
                return;
            }
            var id = GetWindowThreadProcessId((IntPtr)hwnd, out uint i);
            TestStack.White.Application application = TestStack.White.Application.Attach((int)i);
            Debug.WriteLine($"{application.Name}");
            TestStack.White.UIItems.WindowItems.Window window = application.GetWindow("Sound");

            var exists = window.Exists(TestStack.White.UIItems.Finders.SearchCriteria.ByText(driverName));
            if (exists)
            {
                TestStack.White.UIItems.ListBoxItems.ListItem listItem = window.Get<TestStack.White.UIItems.ListBoxItems.ListItem>(TestStack.White.UIItems.Finders.SearchCriteria.ByText(driverName));

                listItem.Focus();
                window.Keyboard.PressSpecialKey(TestStack.White.WindowsAPI.KeyboardInput.SpecialKeys.UP);
                window.Keyboard.PressSpecialKey(TestStack.White.WindowsAPI.KeyboardInput.SpecialKeys.DOWN);

                window.Keyboard.HoldKey(TestStack.White.WindowsAPI.KeyboardInput.SpecialKeys.SHIFT);
                window.Keyboard.PressSpecialKey(TestStack.White.WindowsAPI.KeyboardInput.SpecialKeys.F10);
                window.Keyboard.LeaveKey(TestStack.White.WindowsAPI.KeyboardInput.SpecialKeys.SHIFT);
                window.Keyboard.Enter("E");

            }
            else
            {
                window.Keyboard.HoldKey(TestStack.White.WindowsAPI.KeyboardInput.SpecialKeys.SHIFT);
                window.Keyboard.PressSpecialKey(TestStack.White.WindowsAPI.KeyboardInput.SpecialKeys.F10);
                window.Keyboard.LeaveKey(TestStack.White.WindowsAPI.KeyboardInput.SpecialKeys.SHIFT);
                window.Keyboard.Enter("S");
                window.Keyboard.PressSpecialKey(TestStack.White.WindowsAPI.KeyboardInput.SpecialKeys.RETURN);
                TestStack.White.UIItems.ListBoxItems.ListItem listItem = window.Get<TestStack.White.UIItems.ListBoxItems.ListItem>(TestStack.White.UIItems.Finders.SearchCriteria.ByText(driverName));

                listItem.Focus();
                window.Keyboard.PressSpecialKey(TestStack.White.WindowsAPI.KeyboardInput.SpecialKeys.UP);
                window.Keyboard.PressSpecialKey(TestStack.White.WindowsAPI.KeyboardInput.SpecialKeys.DOWN);

                window.Keyboard.HoldKey(TestStack.White.WindowsAPI.KeyboardInput.SpecialKeys.SHIFT);
                window.Keyboard.PressSpecialKey(TestStack.White.WindowsAPI.KeyboardInput.SpecialKeys.F10);
                window.Keyboard.LeaveKey(TestStack.White.WindowsAPI.KeyboardInput.SpecialKeys.SHIFT);
                window.Keyboard.Enter("E");

            }
            if (mMDevice != null)
            {
                if (mMDevice.State == DeviceState.Active)
                {
                    Debug.WriteLine($"{ mMDevice.FriendlyName}");
                    CloseWindow((IntPtr)hwnd);
                }
                else
                {

                    MessageBox.Show("Please Enable the device ");

                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {

        }

    }
 }
  }
```

**If you have Admin privileges**

```
 private void EnableAsAdmin()
        {
            string driverName = "Stereo Mix";
            string deviceId = "";
            
            
            MMDevice mMDevice;
            using (var enumerator = new NAudio.CoreAudioApi.MMDeviceEnumerator())
            {
                mMDevice = enumerator.EnumerateAudioEndPoints(DataFlow.Capture, DeviceState.Disabled).ToList().Where(d => d.FriendlyName.ToLower().Contains(driverName.ToLower())).FirstOrDefault();
            }
            if (mMDevice != null)
            {
                driverName = mMDevice.FriendlyName;
                int charLocation = driverName.IndexOf("(", StringComparison.Ordinal);

                if (charLocation > 0)
                {
                    driverName = driverName.Substring(0, charLocation);
                    driverName = driverName.Trim();
                }

                deviceId = mMDevice.ID;
                charLocation = deviceId.IndexOf(".{", StringComparison.Ordinal);

                if (charLocation > 0)
                {
                    deviceId = deviceId.Substring(charLocation + 1);
                    deviceId = deviceId.Trim();
                }

                if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(deviceId) && AdminHelper.IsRunAsAdmin())
                {
                    if (Environment.Is64BitOperatingSystem)
                    {

                        RegistryKey localKey =
                            RegistryKey.OpenBaseKey(Microsoft.Win32.RegistryHive.LocalMachine,
                                RegistryView.Registry64);
                        localKey = localKey.OpenSubKey(@"SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\MMDevices\Audio\Capture\" + deviceId, RegistryKeyPermissionCheck.ReadWriteSubTree, RegistryRights.SetValue);
                        localKey.SetValue("DeviceState", 1, RegistryValueKind.DWord);
                    }
                    else
                    {

                        RegistryKey localKey32 =
                            RegistryKey.OpenBaseKey(Microsoft.Win32.RegistryHive.LocalMachine,
                                RegistryView.Registry32);
                        localKey32 = localKey32.OpenSubKey(@"SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\MMDevices\Audio\Capture\" + deviceId, RegistryKeyPermissionCheck.ReadWriteSubTree, RegistryRights.SetValue);
     localKey32.SetValue("DeviceState", 1, RegistryValueKind.DWord);
                    }
                }
                if (mMDevice != null)
                {
                    if (mMDevice.State == DeviceState.Active)
                    {
                        App.Current.Dispatcher.Invoke(() =>
                        {
                            MessageBox.Show($"{driverName} Enabled ");
                        });
                    }
                }
            }
            else
            {
                App.Current.Dispatcher.Invoke(() =>
                {
                    MessageBox.Show($"{driverName} Coudn't Found as Disabled Device.");
                });
                return;
            }
        }
```

**Is there any other solution?**

Answer (score 4):

Here you go, Console App code that enables any audio capture devices that are in a disabled state. you may compile to exe using VS or call with PowerShell using add-type

```
using System;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

namespace ConsoleApp1_Audio
{
    class Program
    {
        public enum HRESULT : uint
        {
            S_OK = 0,
            S_FALSE = 1,
            E_NOINTERFACE = 0x80004002,
            E_NOTIMPL = 0x80004001,
            E_FAIL = 0x80004005,
            E_UNEXPECTED = 0x8000FFFF
        }

        [ComImport]
        [Guid("886D8EEB-8CF2-4446-8D02-CDBA1DBDCF99")]
        [InterfaceType(ComInterfaceType.InterfaceIsIUnknown)]
        public partial interface IPropertyStore
        {
            HRESULT GetCount(out uint propertyCount);
            HRESULT GetAt([In] uint propertyIndex, [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Struct)] out PROPERTYKEY key);
            HRESULT GetValue([In][MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Struct)] ref PROPERTYKEY key, [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Struct)] out PROPVARIANT pv);
            HRESULT SetValue([In][MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Struct)] ref PROPERTYKEY key, [In][MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Struct)] ref PROPVARIANT pv);
            HRESULT Commit();
        }

        public const int STGM_READ = 0x0;
        public const int STGM_WRITE = 0x1;
        public const int STGM_READWRITE = 0x2;

        public partial struct PROPERTYKEY
        {
            public PROPERTYKEY(Guid InputId, uint InputPid)
            {
                fmtid = InputId;
                pid = InputPid;
            }

            private Guid fmtid;
            private uint pid;
        }

        [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
        public partial struct PROPARRAY
        {
            public uint cElems;
            public IntPtr pElems;
        }

        [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Explicit, Pack = 1)]
        public partial struct PROPVARIANT
        {
            [FieldOffset(0)]
            public ushort varType;
            [FieldOffset(2)]
            public ushort wReserved1;
            [FieldOffset(4)]
            public ushort wReserved2;
            [FieldOffset(6)]
            public ushort wReserved3;
            [FieldOffset(8)]
            public byte bVal;
            [FieldOffset(8)]
            public sbyte cVal;
            [FieldOffset(8)]
            public ushort uiVal;
            [FieldOffset(8)]
            public short iVal;
            [FieldOffset(8)]
            public uint uintVal;
            [FieldOffset(8)]
            public int intVal;
            [FieldOffset(8)]
            public ulong ulVal;
            [FieldOffset(8)]
            public long lVal;
            [FieldOffset(8)]
            public float fltVal;
            [FieldOffset(8)]
            public double dblVal;
            [FieldOffset(8)]
            public short boolVal;
            [FieldOffset(8)]
            public IntPtr pclsidVal;
            [FieldOffset(8)]
            public IntPtr pszVal;
            [FieldOffset(8)]
            public IntPtr pwszVal;
            [FieldOffset(8)]
            public IntPtr punkVal;
            [FieldOffset(8)]
            public PROPARRAY ca;
            [FieldOffset(8)]
            public System.Runtime.InteropServices.ComTypes.FILETIME filetime;
        }

        public enum EDataFlow
        {
            eRender = 0,
            eCapture = eRender + 1,
            eAll = eCapture + 1,
            EDataFlow_enum_count = eAll + 1
        }

        public enum ERole
        {
            eConsole = 0,
            eMultimedia = eConsole + 1,
            eCommunications = eMultimedia + 1,
            ERole_enum_count = eCommunications + 1
        }

        [ComImport]
        [Guid("A95664D2-9614-4F35-A746-DE8DB63617E6")]
        [InterfaceType(ComInterfaceType.InterfaceIsIUnknown)]
        public partial interface IMMDeviceEnumerator
        {
            HRESULT EnumAudioEndpoints(EDataFlow dataFlow, int dwStateMask, out IMMDeviceCollection ppDevices);
            // for 0x80070490 : Element not found
            [PreserveSig]
            HRESULT GetDefaultAudioEndpoint(EDataFlow dataFlow, ERole role, out IMMDevice ppEndpoint);
            HRESULT GetDevice(string pwstrId, out IMMDevice ppDevice);
            HRESULT RegisterEndpointNotificationCallback(IMMNotificationClient pClient);
            HRESULT UnregisterEndpointNotificationCallback(IMMNotificationClient pClient);
        }

        public const int DEVICE_STATE_ACTIVE = 0x1;
        public const int DEVICE_STATE_DISABLED = 0x2;
        public const int DEVICE_STATE_NOTPRESENT = 0x4;
        public const int DEVICE_STATE_UNPLUGGED = 0x8;
        public const int DEVICE_STATEMASK_ALL = 0xF;

        [ComImport]
        [Guid("0BD7A1BE-7A1A-44DB-8397-CC5392387B5E")]
        [InterfaceType(ComInterfaceType.InterfaceIsIUnknown)]
        public partial interface IMMDeviceCollection
        {
            HRESULT GetCount(out uint pcDevices);
            HRESULT Item(uint nDevice, out IMMDevice ppDevice);
        }

        [ComImport]
        [Guid("D666063F-1587-4E43-81F1-B948E807363F")]
        [InterfaceType(ComInterfaceType.InterfaceIsIUnknown)]
        public partial interface IMMDevice
        {
            HRESULT Activate(ref Guid iid, int dwClsCtx, ref PROPVARIANT pActivationParams, out IntPtr ppInterface);
            HRESULT OpenPropertyStore(int stgmAccess, out IPropertyStore ppProperties);
            HRESULT GetId(out IntPtr ppstrId);
            HRESULT GetState(out int pdwState);
        }

        [ComImport]
        [Guid("7991EEC9-7E89-4D85-8390-6C703CEC60C0")]
        [InterfaceType(ComInterfaceType.InterfaceIsIUnknown)]
        public partial interface IMMNotificationClient
        {
            HRESULT OnDeviceStateChanged(string pwstrDeviceId, int dwNewState);
            HRESULT OnDeviceAdded(string pwstrDeviceId);
            HRESULT OnDeviceRemoved(string pwstrDeviceId);
            HRESULT OnDefaultDeviceChanged(EDataFlow flow, ERole role, string pwstrDefaultDeviceId);
            HRESULT OnPropertyValueChanged(string pwstrDeviceId, ref PROPERTYKEY key);
        }

        [ComImport]
        [Guid("1BE09788-6894-4089-8586-9A2A6C265AC5")]
        [InterfaceType(ComInterfaceType.InterfaceIsIUnknown)]
        public partial interface IMMEndpoint
        {
            HRESULT GetDataFlow(out EDataFlow pDataFlow);
        }

        [ComImport]
        [Guid("f8679f50-850a-41cf-9c72-430f290290c8")]
        [InterfaceType(ComInterfaceType.InterfaceIsIUnknown)]
        public partial interface IPolicyConfig
        {
            HRESULT GetMixFormat([In][MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPWStr)] string pszDeviceName, out WAVEFORMATEXTENSIBLE ppFormat);
            HRESULT GetDeviceFormat([In][MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPWStr)] string pszDeviceName, [In][MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)] bool bDefault, out WAVEFORMATEXTENSIBLE ppFormat);
            HRESULT ResetDeviceFormat([In][MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPWStr)] string pszDeviceName);
            HRESULT SetDeviceFormat([In][MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPWStr)] string pszDeviceName, [In][MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPStruct)] WAVEFORMATEXTENSIBLE pEndpointFormat, [In][MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPStruct)] WAVEFORMATEXTENSIBLE pMixFormat);
            HRESULT GetProcessingPeriod([In][MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPWStr)] string pszDeviceName, [In][MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)] bool bDefault, out long pmftDefaultPeriod, out long pmftMinimumPeriod);
            HRESULT SetProcessingPeriod([In][MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPWStr)] string pszDeviceName, long pmftPeriod);
            HRESULT GetShareMode([In][MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPWStr)] string pszDeviceName, out DeviceShareMode pMode);
            HRESULT SetShareMode([In][MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPWStr)] string pszDeviceName, [In] DeviceShareMode mode);
            HRESULT GetPropertyValue([In][MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPWStr)] string pszDeviceName, [In][MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)] bool bFxStore, ref PROPERTYKEY pKey, out PROPVARIANT pv);
            HRESULT SetPropertyValue([In][MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPWStr)] string pszDeviceName, [In][MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)] bool bFxStore, [In] ref PROPERTYKEY pKey, ref PROPVARIANT pv);
            HRESULT SetDefaultEndpoint([In][MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPWStr)] string pszDeviceName, [In][MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.U4)] ERole role);
            HRESULT SetEndpointVisibility([In][MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPWStr)] string pszDeviceName, [In][MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)] bool bVisible);
        }

        [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Explicit, Pack = 1)]
        public partial class WAVEFORMATEXTENSIBLE : WAVEFORMATEX
        {
            [FieldOffset(0)]
            public short wValidBitsPerSample;
            [FieldOffset(0)]
            public short wSamplesPerBlock;
            [FieldOffset(0)]
            public short wReserved;
            [FieldOffset(2)]
            public WaveMask dwChannelMask;
            [FieldOffset(6)]
            public Guid SubFormat;
        }

        [Flags]
        public enum WaveMask
        {
            None = 0x0,
            FrontLeft = 0x1,
            FrontRight = 0x2,
            FrontCenter = 0x4,
            LowFrequency = 0x8,
            BackLeft = 0x10,
            BackRight = 0x20,
            FrontLeftOfCenter = 0x40,
            FrontRightOfCenter = 0x80,
            BackCenter = 0x100,
            SideLeft = 0x200,
            SideRight = 0x400,
            TopCenter = 0x800,
            TopFrontLeft = 0x1000,
            TopFrontCenter = 0x2000,
            TopFrontRight = 0x4000,
            TopBackLeft = 0x8000,
            TopBackCenter = 0x10000,
            TopBackRight = 0x20000
        }

        [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential, Pack = 2)]
        public partial class WAVEFORMATEX
        {
            public short wFormatTag;
            public short nChannels;
            public int nSamplesPerSec;
            public int nAvgBytesPerSec;
            public short nBlockAlign;
            public short wBitsPerSample;
            public short cbSize;
        }

        public enum DeviceShareMode
        {
            Shared,
            Exclusive
        }

        [DllImport("Shlwapi.dll", SetLastError = true, CharSet = CharSet.Unicode)]
        public static extern int PathParseIconLocationW(string pszIconFile);

        public static PROPERTYKEY PKEY_Device_FriendlyName = new PROPERTYKEY(new Guid("a45c254e-df1c-4efd-8020-67d146a850e0"), 14);
        public static PROPERTYKEY PKEY_Device_DeviceDesc = new PROPERTYKEY(new Guid("a45c254e-df1c-4efd-8020-67d146a850e0"), 2);
        public static PROPERTYKEY PKEY_DeviceClass_IconPath = new PROPERTYKEY(new Guid("259abffc-50a7-47ce-af08-68c9a7d73366"), 12);
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            EnableMicsThatAreDisabled();
        }

        public static void EnableMicsThatAreDisabled()
        {
            var hr = HRESULT.E_FAIL;
            var CLSID_MMDeviceEnumerator = new Guid("{BCDE0395-E52F-467C-8E3D-C4579291692E}");
            var MMDeviceEnumeratorType = Type.GetTypeFromCLSID(CLSID_MMDeviceEnumerator, true);
            var MMDeviceEnumerator = Activator.CreateInstance(MMDeviceEnumeratorType);
            IMMDeviceEnumerator pMMDeviceEnumerator = (IMMDeviceEnumerator)MMDeviceEnumerator;
            if (pMMDeviceEnumerator is object)
            {
                string sIdDefaultRender = null;
                string sIdDefaultCapture = null;
                IMMDevice pDefaultDevice = null;
                hr = pMMDeviceEnumerator.GetDefaultAudioEndpoint(EDataFlow.eRender, ERole.eConsole, out pDefaultDevice);
                if (hr == HRESULT.S_OK)
                {
                    var hGlobal = Marshal.AllocHGlobal(260);
                    hr = pDefaultDevice.GetId(out hGlobal);
                    sIdDefaultRender = Marshal.PtrToStringUni(hGlobal);
                    Marshal.FreeHGlobal(hGlobal);
                    Marshal.ReleaseComObject(pDefaultDevice);
                }

                hr = pMMDeviceEnumerator.GetDefaultAudioEndpoint(EDataFlow.eCapture, ERole.eConsole, out pDefaultDevice);
                if (hr == HRESULT.S_OK)
                {
                    var hGlobal = Marshal.AllocHGlobal(260);
                    hr = pDefaultDevice.GetId(out hGlobal);
                    sIdDefaultCapture = Marshal.PtrToStringUni(hGlobal);
                    Marshal.FreeHGlobal(hGlobal);
                    Marshal.ReleaseComObject(pDefaultDevice);
                }

                IMMDeviceCollection pDeviceCollection = null;
                //hr = pMMDeviceEnumerator.EnumAudioEndpoints(EDataFlow.eAll, DEVICE_STATE_ACTIVE | DEVICE_STATE_UNPLUGGED | DEVICE_STATE_DISABLED, out pDeviceCollection);
                hr = pMMDeviceEnumerator.EnumAudioEndpoints(EDataFlow.eAll, DEVICE_STATE_DISABLED, out pDeviceCollection);
                if (hr == HRESULT.S_OK)
                {
                    uint nDevices = 0;
                    hr = pDeviceCollection.GetCount(out nDevices);
                    if (nDevices == 0) //Return when no devices are enumerated.
                    {
                        return;
                    }
                    for (uint i = 0, loopTo = (uint)(nDevices - (long)1); i <= loopTo; i++)
                    {
                        IMMDevice pDevice = null;
                        hr = pDeviceCollection.Item(i, out pDevice);
                        if (hr == HRESULT.S_OK)
                        {
                            IPropertyStore pPropertyStore = null;
                            hr = pDevice.OpenPropertyStore(STGM_READ, out pPropertyStore);
                            if (hr == HRESULT.S_OK)
                            {
                                string sFriendlyName = null;
                                var pv = new PROPVARIANT();
                                hr = pPropertyStore.GetValue(ref PKEY_Device_FriendlyName, out pv);
                                if (hr == HRESULT.S_OK)
                                {
                                    sFriendlyName = Marshal.PtrToStringUni(pv.pwszVal);
                                }

                                string sIconPath = null;
                                int nIconId = 0;
                                var pvIconPath = new PROPVARIANT();
                                hr = pPropertyStore.GetValue(ref PKEY_DeviceClass_IconPath, out pvIconPath);
                                if (hr == HRESULT.S_OK)
                                {
                                    // %windir%\system32\mmres.dll,-3011
                                    sIconPath = Marshal.PtrToStringUni(pvIconPath.pwszVal);
                                    nIconId = PathParseIconLocationW(sIconPath);
                                }

                                var hGlobal = Marshal.AllocHGlobal(260);
                                hr = pDevice.GetId(out hGlobal);
                                string sId = Marshal.PtrToStringUni(hGlobal);
                                Marshal.FreeHGlobal(hGlobal);
                                IMMEndpoint pEndpoint = null;
                                pEndpoint = (IMMEndpoint)pDevice;
                                var eDirection = EDataFlow.eAll;
                                hr = pEndpoint.GetDataFlow(out eDirection);
                                int nState = 0;
                                string sState = "";
                                hr = pDevice.GetState(out nState);
                                if (nState == DEVICE_STATE_ACTIVE)
                                {
                                    sState = "Active";
                                }
                                else if (nState == DEVICE_STATE_DISABLED)
                                {
                                    sState = "Disabled";
                                }
                                else if (nState == DEVICE_STATE_NOTPRESENT)
                                {
                                    sState = "Not present";
                                }
                                else if (nState == DEVICE_STATE_UNPLUGGED)
                                {
                                    sState = "Unplugged";
                                }
                                if (eDirection == EDataFlow.eRender)
                                {

                                }
                                else if (eDirection == EDataFlow.eCapture)
                                {

                                    Console.WriteLine(sFriendlyName );
                                    EnableMic(sId, sState);
                                }

                                Marshal.ReleaseComObject(pPropertyStore);
                            }

                            Marshal.ReleaseComObject(pDevice);
                        }
                    }

                    Marshal.ReleaseComObject(pDeviceCollection);
                }

                Marshal.ReleaseComObject(pMMDeviceEnumerator);
            }
        }
        private static void EnableMic(string sCurrentId, string sState)
        {
            var hr = HRESULT.E_FAIL;
            var CLSID_PolicyConfig = new Guid("{870af99c-171d-4f9e-af0d-e63df40c2bc9}");
            var PolicyConfigType = Type.GetTypeFromCLSID(CLSID_PolicyConfig, true);
            var PolicyConfig = Activator.CreateInstance(PolicyConfigType);
            IPolicyConfig pPolicyConfig = (IPolicyConfig)PolicyConfig;
            bool bEnable = false;
            if (pPolicyConfig is object)
            {
                if (sState == "Disabled")
                {
                    bEnable = true;
                }
                else
                {
                    bEnable = false;
                }

                hr = pPolicyConfig.SetEndpointVisibility(sCurrentId, bEnable);                
                Marshal.ReleaseComObject(PolicyConfig);
            }
        }
    }
 }
```