# Why can I change a value in the Registry editor, but not in my C# form app running as administrator?

Tags: c#, windows, security, audio, registry

I try to enable a sound device in C#. This leads to `System.Security.SecurityException: 'Requested registry access is not allowed.'`. Just loading (reading) the key works, so the path is correct.

The same happens even if I run the C# program as Administrator.

```
string baseKeyName = device.RegistryPath;
RegistryKey localMachine = RegistryKey.OpenBaseKey(Microsoft.Win32.RegistryHive.LocalMachine, RegistryView.Registry64);
RegistryKey? regKey = localMachine.OpenSubKey(baseKeyName, true);
// System.Security.SecurityException: 'Requested registry access is not allowed.'
if (regKey == null) return false; // with false (read only) I get the regKey
                
regKey.SetValue("DeviceState", deviceState, RegistryValueKind.DWord);
regKey.Close();
```

Doing the same in `Registry Editor` works just fine.

Any idea why the permissions is not granted in C#?

[image: Registry editor]

Update 1:

I have tried `RegistryView.Registry64` and `RegistryView.Registry32` (does not yield the key) without success. It is simply no update possible (read only works), even though the program runs as Administrator.

Update 2:

I did not expect it to work, as I have already tried with "Run as Administrator". But `<requestedExecutionLevel  level="highestAvailable" uiAccess="false" />` in a manifest did not help either.

---

Related topics and links

1. [Win32 API function to programmatically enable/disable device](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1438371/win32-api-function-to-programmatically-enable-disable-device)
2. https://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/80323-enable-disable-microphone-windows.html
3. [Enabling recording devices programmatically](https://stackoverflow.com/q/52954849/356726)

Comment: maybe this link could help you:
[requested-registry-access-is-not-allowed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/562350/requested-registry-access-is-not-allowed)

Comment: Are you running as a 32-bit or 64-bit app.  They each have a different view of the registry

Comment: Good point, thanks for the 32/64 bit hint (both of you)!

Comment: I have tried `RegistryView.Registry64` and `RegistryView.Registry32` (does not yield the key) without success. It is simply no update possible (read only works), even though the program runs as Administrator.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Original question [How do I programmatically give ownership of a Registry Key to Administrators?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38448390/356726)

The registry access right problem is solved with these two answers:

1. https://stackoverflow.com/a/38727406/356726
2. https://stackoverflow.com/a/17047190/356726

However, changing the sound devices this way causes a "kind of hanging" of the devices and requires a restart. While technically working it is not a solution for me, but this is another topic.

Remark: The "overall" solution to enable/disable audio devices without admin rights is here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/53017704/356726